# Javascript dropdown has a case for multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, case

I am trying to create a dropdown that reveals multiple pre-set text.

So, if I selected A from the dropdown 1,2,3,4,5 will display in sepearte areas on the page - so A has the values set in a case statement or something like that?
If I'd then selected B from the dropdown, 2,4,6,8,10 would display where the previous values were displayed - basically replacing them on page.

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: please post what you have tried..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking to do.

**JS Fiddle example**
https://jsfiddle.net/ogvbe3mq/1/

HTML

```
<select id="ddl">
  <option value='0'>Select One</option>
  <option value='A'>A</option>
  <option value='B'>B</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div id='content1'>
</div>
<div id='content2'>
</div>
<div id='content3'>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('ddl').addEventListener('change', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var e = document.getElementById('ddl');
  var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  switch(val) {
    case "A" : document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML = "1";
               document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = "2";
               document.getElementById('content3').innerHTML = "3";
               break;
    case "B" : document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML = "4";
               document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = "5";
               document.getElementById('content3').innerHTML = "6";
               break;
    default : document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML = "";
              document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = "";
              document.getElementById('content3').innerHTML = "";
              break;

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks wizloc.  Yes almost but seperating the values that display too so 1 2 3 are in a seperate div but when selecting B, 1 2 3 get replaced with 4 5 6

Comment: Updated, give that a try

Comment: Ah, I see what you've done! That's actually obvious too! Thank you Wizloc.